# Any JQuery alert() replacement for JavaScript's native one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I would like to replace the native JavaScript `alert()` with my own, so that I would be able to control the theme and have it more JQueryUI look and feel.
I've tried numerous alternatives - JQueryUI Dialog, jAlert, jqAlert.
However, it appears that all of them not functioning synchronously in the same fashion like the original alert.

Example:

```
function mytest()
{
    alert('one');
    alert('two');
    alert('three');
}
```

In this example, with the original `alert()`, the 3 dialogs would appear one after the other in a row. But in the substitutes, they appear all at once!

Any idea?

Comment: just chain the jQuery UI dialogs using callback functions.

Answer (score 13):

The native `alert()` brings the browser to a **dead halt.** You will not find any third party libraries that do that, because it's not possible.*

---

### Edit

I threw together a quick demo of how you can use a single jQuery dialog instead of an alert.

```
var alertManager = (function() {
    var _queue = [],
        _opts = {
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            buttons: {
                OK: function ()
                {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    var next = _queue.shift();
                    if (typeof next === 'string')
                    {
                        _dialog.text(next).dialog('open');
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        _dialog = $('<div id="alertDialog" title="Alert!"></div>').dialog(_opts),

        _self = {};

    _self.show = function (message) {
        if (_dialog.dialog('isOpen')) {
            _queue.push(String(message));
        }
        else {
            _dialog.text(message).dialog('open');
        }
    }

    return _self;
}());



$('#clicky').click(function ()
{
    alertManager.show('alert numero uno');
    alertManager.show('alert #2');
    alertManager.show({foo: 'bar'});
    alertManager.show(document.getElementById('clicky'));
    alertManager.show('last one');
});
```

#### [Hot demo action over here →](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/8zbnf/2/)

You could also turn this into a jQuery plugin pretty easily.

---

<sub>*though you could fake it with a `while` loop that spins while the dialog is open. I **do not** recommend this.</sub>

Comment: This is better left as a (cheeky) comment. The OP probably doesn't want to bring the browser to a dead halt, but rather have the dialog boxes display one after the other.

Comment: @Jasie well the OP asks for something that functions "in the same fashion like the original alert": synchronously.  Thus the OP almost certainly **does** want to bring the browser to a dead halt.

Comment: I have already tried while loop, it causes the browser to complete halt not being able to see the dialog, not to mention that the browser gives a warning about stopping unresponsive script.

Comment: @Nir O: okay, so do you actually want to totally halt the browser, or just ensure that you only show 1 alert at a time? If it's the former, **use the native `alert()`.** If it's the latter, just manage your own dialogs accordingly.

Comment: I wanted to use the original alert() with the look&feel of my app. I guess that I will have to chain functions, which I didn't want to do.

Comment: @Nir O: if all you want to do is make sure you don't display more than one dialog at a time, this is really not that hard to implement. Instead of calling `window.alert` you could write a simple "alertManager" object... screw it, let me write a demo

Comment: @Matt: this is not real synchronized code execution. I changed your code to that:     alertManager.show('alert numero uno');
    alert('real alert');
    alertManager.show('alert #2');
    alertManager.show({foo: 'bar'});
    alertManager.show(document.getElementById('clicky'));
    alertManager.show('last one'); and the first (emulated) and second (native) alerts were shown together.

Comment: @Nir O: I'm aware. **You cannot write your own "synchronized" version of alert that halts everything in the browser.** If you want the custom skin, use jQuery. If you need the browser to halt while the alert is shown, **use `window.alert()`**. It's that simple.

Answer (score 4):

I found a library a long time ago that solved this problem for alert, prompt, and confirm, it is pretty easy to use:

Demo here: http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/

```
// Usage:
//      jAlert( message, [title, callback] )
//      jConfirm( message, [title, callback] )
//      jPrompt( message, [value, title, callback] )
```

download here: http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/jquery.alerts-1.1.zip

Answer (score 2):

<strike>a jquery alert:</strike>

```
  JQuery.fn.alert = function(message) {
     alert(message);
  };
```

example of using:

```
 $("#item1").alert("hello");
```

oh my god :D

the jquery is only a DOM framework. this not an other javascript! jquery is only some javascript lines. and not replacing javascript.

if you want to create a dialog box then i can suggest you to search for jquery plugin.

http://choosedaily.com/1178/15-jquery-popup-modal-dialog-plugins-tutorials/

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking also for alternative behavior you might wanna try:
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/freeow

it also alerts the user but does not lock the browser as "Matt Ball" said

Comment: This can also help you with showing several alerts at the same time since they appear one below the other instead of appearing on top of each other

Answer (score 0):

You can easily mimic the synchronicity of regular js alerts using jQueryUI Dialog boxes. Simply use the events provided -- in this case, `close`, which is called when you close a dialog box:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">Dialog</div>
<div id="dialog2" title="Dialog Title">Another dialog</div>
$("#dialog").dialog({
    close: function(event, ui) {
        $("#dialog2").dialog();
    }
});
```

Now, when you close the first dialog, the second opens.

Answer (score 0):

You can use and perfectly control this ui dialogs http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Just evoke them when needed.

Comment: I already tested JQuery UI Dialog, and it doesn't work synchronizely.

Comment: Maybe using a flag variable. var dialogOpened = true; combination with another custom event for each dialog.

Answer (score 0):

How about layering the alerts ?
They'll still appear all at once, but the user only sees the first, until she closes that, then the second appears (is revealed) and so forth.
- Could easily be acheaved by updating a "global" last-z-index variable..

Answer (score 0):

In the mean time i also recently created a new function to allow confirm boxes with jqueryui dialog.

It is extremely easy to use

```
dlgConfirm('Are you sure you want to cancel this change-email request? <br><label>Current password<br><input type="password"></label>',
             'Cancel Email Change', 'Continue', function(dlg){
       //do ajax or something
       return false; //do not close dialog until ajax is complete
    }

dlgConfirm('Are you sure you want to submit this form', function(dlg){
    $('form', dlg).submit();
    return true;
});
```

Here is the source code (public domain):

```
<script>
   /**
    * Open confirmation dialog (jqueryui modal)
    *
    * @param {string} c_text text/html to show in the dialog box
    * @param {string|function(dlg_element)} c_title|confirm_callback title of the dialog box (or callback function)
    * @param {string|function(dlg_element)} c_btn_text|confirm_callback confirm button text (or callback function)
    * @param {string|function(dlg_element)} c_btn_cancel_text|confirm_callback cancel button text (defaults to 'Cancel') (or callback function)
    * @param {function(dlg_element)} confirm_callback callback after the modal box is confirmed 
    */
   function dlgConfirm(c_text, c_title, c_btn_text, c_btn_cancel_text, confirm_callback){

      if (typeof(confirm_callback) !== 'function'){
         if (typeof(c_title) == 'function'){
            confirm_callback = c_title;
         }else if (typeof(c_btn_text) == 'function'){
            confirm_callback = c_btn_text;
         }else if (typeof(c_btn_cancel_text) == 'function'){
            confirm_callback = c_btn_cancel_text;
         }
      }

      if (typeof(c_text) !== 'string'){
         c_text = 'Are you sure?';
      }
      if (typeof(c_title) !== 'string'){
         c_title = 'Confirm';
      }  
      if (typeof(c_btn_text) !== 'string'){
         c_btn_text = 'Confirm';
      }  
      if (typeof(c_btn_cancel_text) !== 'string'){
         c_btn_cancel_text = 'Cancel';
      }     

      if ($('#dlgConfirm').length == 0){
         $('body').append('<div id="dlgConfirm" title="Confirm" style="display: none">Are you sure?</div>');
      }
      var btns = {};
      btns[c_btn_text] = function() {
             var dlg = this;
             if (typeof(confirm_callback) == 'function'){
                if (confirm_callback(dlg) !== false){
                   $(this).dialog('close');
                }
             }          
      };
      btns[c_btn_cancel_text] = function() {
             $( this ).dialog("close");
      };

      $('#dlgConfirm').dialog({
         title: c_title,
         autoOpen: false,
         resizable: false,
         //height:170, //commented out so autosize works
         modal: true,
         buttons: btns
       }).html(c_text).dialog('open');
   }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[DAlert jQuery UI Plugin](http://andrewdex.github.io/dalert) Try this: andrewdex.github.io/dalert