# JQuery Dialog syncronous call

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I have implemented a JQuery Dialog to replace all standard alert() and confirm() to give a better look and feel.

The problems is these are async call and in most places I can use the callback method to fire the action after user response.

But in another plugin I can utilise the callback so need this to be syncronous.

Example:

1. some js code
2. dialog
3. more js code

Line 1,2 & 3 are fired before line 2 dialog has been completed by the user. I dont need the response from the dialog just for it to stop the execution of line 3.

Comment: can u show some code here or on jsfiddle?

Comment: Will the dialog be displayed for a certain amount of time? Does the user have to click OK of some sort to continue? What has to happen?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any JQuery alert() replacement for JavaScript's native one?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913594/any-jquery-alert-replacement-for-javascripts-native-one)

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of what i think u want to do:

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/32BWw/

js:

```
function step_one(){
    $('body').append('hello');
    step_two();
}
function step_two(){

    $('<div>').dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            ok: function(){
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        },
        beforeClose: function(){
            step_three();
        }
    }).html('you sure?')

}
function step_three(){
    $('body').append(' there');
}


step_one();
```

you need callbacks for the closing dialog step